# Batch File Closing When I Try To Drag Variables

Tags: batch-file

I am currently coding (in batch) a mini tycoon game. However,
I'm having some difficulties when executing this command:

```
:cantbuy
echo Insufficient Funds!
pause
goto shop

:buy1
set /p money<"m2df.dll"
set /p cps<"m3df.dll"
if %money% GTR 100 goto canbuy1
goto cantbuy
:canbuy1
set /a "newmoney=%money%-100"
set /a "newcps=%cps%+2"
set cps=%newcps%
set money=%newmoney%
echo %money%>m2df.dll
echo %cps%>m3df.dll
echo Bought!
pause
goto shop
```

The program seems to exit straight after I input "1"
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Found It Out. I decided to put a pause after everything to see what was wrong, and the syntax was bad and it went straight to another command crashing the script. here's the fixed script:

```
:cantbuy   
echo Insufficient Funds!
pause
goto shop

:buy1
set /p money=<"m2df.dll"
set /p cps=<"m3df.dll"
if %money% GEQ 100 goto canbuy1
goto cantbuy
:canbuy1
set /a "newmoney=%money%-100"
set money=%newmoney%
set /a "newcps=%cps%+2"
set cps=%newcps%
echo %cps% >m3df.dll
echo %money% >m2df.dll
echo Bought!
pause
goto shop
```

Comment: Always open the command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking it for debugging purposes.